# Run a shell script in new terminal from current terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

How do you run a shell script in a new terminal in Linux from a terminal like "start test.bat" in Windows, also it should be working in the console mode.

Comment: which window environment(s) do you need to support?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started:

To write a shell script, do this on your command prompt:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\n echo "hello world"' > abc.sh
```

This writes:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```

To a file called `abc.sh`

Next, you want to set it to executable by:

```
chmod +x abc.sh
```

Now, you can run it by:

```
./abc.sh
```

And you should see:

```
hello world
```

On your terminal.

To run it in a new terminal, you can do:

```
gnome-terminal -x ./abc.sh
```

or, if it's `xterm`:

```
xterm -e ./abc.sh
```

Here's a [list of different terminal emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators).

Alternatively, you just run it in your current terminal, but background it instead by:

```
./abc.sh &
```

Comment: it works fineThank you so much for your help, and i have a another doubt will all the types of linux os support gnome-terminal command?

Comment: @RaviKumar No, that is not in general true. It largely depends on what desktop environment that linux distro uses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators Quite often it's gnome-terminal or xterm

Comment: also i need the command that should be working when i use the linux machine in the telnet session. i hope there will be answer for this.

Comment: @RaviKumar I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm a windows user, I have that linux PC in some other location, now i have made the telnet connection with that linux PC from my PC in console mode, now i want to execute that script

Comment: So if you want to spawn a new telnet window to a linux PC from your windows machine, you'll have to launch a new telnet session from your windows environment, otherwise `gnome-terminal -x ./abc.sh` won't be able to spawn a new terminal in your windows environment as far as I know. That's scripting on Windows side, no longer on Unix side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20405/discussion-between-ravikumar-and-sampson-chen)

Comment: Hi Sampson. The shell script I execute in another window needs to hang there. So my original sh file needs to continue to the next line of commands. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Using `-x` and `--command` are equivalent to making the script itself use `#!/bin/bash --init-file` as its shebang in that some programs requiring user interaction don't seem to receive [some?] input when typed.  As an example, if you run Wind River's `vxsim` like this, the only user input the program sees is `^C` and `^backslash`; other text is not passed along.  That does not appear to be the case with `ssh` and I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: @LeoNie maybe its too late because its a old question, but I found out how to hang the script in a new window. Just add new line at end of script like this: exec $SHELL

Answer (score 7):

I came here wanting to figure out how to make a script spawn a terminal and run it self in it, so for those who want to do that I figured out this solution:

```
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then # script is executed outside the terminal?
  # execute the script inside a terminal window with same arguments
  x-terminal-emulator -e "$0" "$@"
  # and abort running the rest of it
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Wait what if the script had arguments called on it? They wont be given to the script in the new terminal, am I right?

Answer (score 4):

As of January 2020, the `-e` and `-x` option in `gnome-terminal` still run properly but throw out the following warnings:

For `-e`:

> # Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version
>   of gnome-terminal.
>
> # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to
>   execute after it.

For `-x`:

> # Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version
>   of gnome-terminal.
>
> # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to
>   execute after it.

Based on that information above, I confirmed that you can run the following two commands without receiving any warning messages:

```sh
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c '<your command>'
```

```sh
gnome-terminal -- ./<your script>.sh
```

I hope this helps anyone else presently having this issue :)

Answer (score 3):

For gnome try this.

Replace ls with the command you want to run

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ls|less"
```

I hope this is what you want