# Have a script run a new linux terminal to run another script within that terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two scripts: `a.py` and `b.py`.
I want `a.py` to run a new terminal. The new terminal will then be running `b.py`.

I have tried many of the solutions on this site with `subprocess.Popen`, `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.run`. None seems to work for me and some of the solutions are outdated. So even tho there are already many questions about this, and possible solutions, I dare to ask the question again for a new updated 2021 solution.

I am using the KDE `konsole`, but `gnome-terminal` or `xfce4-terminal` is also a possibily. A specific terminal is not important.

Comment: What are `a.py` and `b.py`? What is the line of code that calls `subprocess.Popen` / whatever else you've tried? What does "not working" mean - errors, nothing happens, or unexpected behavior? Please clarify.

Comment: This might help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648780/run-a-shell-script-in-new-terminal-from-current-terminal